# hash function for elliptic curve co-ordinates

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, one-way-function

Is there any hash function which takes the co-ordinates of an elliptic curve $E_p(a,b)$ as input and gives an integer value i.e.

$h(.) : \{(x,y) \in E_p(a,b)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What about $H(x + p\cdot y)$ where $H$ is your favorite hash function?

Comment: If this is for a practical application you'd usually just hash (and expand) the x-coordinate of the curve point.

Comment: Choose an encoding for curve points and hash the encoded point. Then interpret the hash as integer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos will that yield a unique value ? I guess that will depend on the encoding algorithm. If the encoded result is unique then hashed output will be unique. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Sandy: The encoding $(x,y) \mapsto x + py$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$) is unique for each point $(x,y)$ on an elliptic curve defined modulo $p$.  Alternatively, you can also encode points as $(x,y)\mapsto x + 2^k y$ for some $k$ such that $2^k > p$.

Comment: @user94293 yeah...$x+py$ is definitely unqiue. But does it provide one-wayness ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ denote the bit-size of $p$.  Let also a hash function $H \colon \{0,1\}^{2k} \to \{0,1\}^\ell$.  We define the hash value of a point $P = (x,y)$ on an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ as
$$h \colon E_p(a,b) \to \mathbb{Z}, (x,y) \mapsto H(x + 2^k y)$$

One-wayness follows from hash function $H$ (for example SHA-3).

*Note.* There is a slight abuse of notation above, integer $x+2^ky$ should be seen as a binary string when applying hash function $H$; and the output (namely, $H(x + 2^k y)$) should be regarded as an integer.  This is done by the canonical representation: a $t$-bit integer $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ can uniquely be represented as $a = \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} a_i 2^i$ with $a_i \in \{0,1\}$, which in turn can be seen as the $t$-bit binary string $a_{t-1}a_{t-2}\ldots a_0$, and conversely.

Comment: Using only the $x$-coordinate does not guarantee collision resistance: both $P=(x,y)$ and $-P=(x,-y)$ would hash to the same value.  Both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the elliptic curve defined over $F_p$. If $\#E=p$ then $E$ is called anomalous elliptic curve. In this curve we can solve discrete logarithm problem in polynomial time. Let $P$ be the base point of this curve. Now  we can easily construct hash function as bellow:

> $$H(Q=k\cdot P)=k.$$